# how to create an eclipse workspace with command line without actually launching eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, command-line, workspace

Is there any command to create an `eclipse` workspace without actually launching `eclipse`? I want the command be part of script. After the workspace is created, it will be configured (e.g., text encoding) then will be used to import project to `RTC`. I know below command is able to crate a new workspace. But the command also tries to import or build or clear-Build a project, which is not I want.

```
eclipse -nosplash 
    -data workspace_name
    -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild 
    -import {[uri:/]/path/to/project} 
    -build {project_name | all} 
    -cleanBuild {projec_name | all}
```

What I want is just a simple command to create a new workspace, nothing else (no importing, no building, no launching `eclipse`)? How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create an empty folder. There is really nothing else you need for an empty workspace.

**Edit:** If you need preferences as well create sub folders `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings` and let your script write `.prefs` files with the settings that you need. Look at the `.prefs` files of an existing workspace to see how they should look.

Comment: an empty folder is different from an empty eclipse-workspace which has a .metadata sub-directory where all setting of workspace is saved. I want to change some configuration in .metadata (e.g., text encoding)

Comment: Do you want to change this configuration from the script? If so, you could just create the folder structure like .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings and then write the needed .prefs file in there. Once Eclipse is started it will pick up the .prefs files the script created and create any other files that it needs.